# VS'15 Exception dialog

Tags: visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2015

I am currently trying to figure out why my exception dialog does not look like this picture of google:

[image: Exception dialog]

Instead it still looks like the exception dialogs I had in VS'10, 12 & 13:

[image: Exception dialog]

I've tried to google for solutions and ask collegues if they had any clue, as they have the "correct" dialog for C#. So far I had no success.

I can only assume that it has something to do with the fact, that I also use C++, though two other collegues do the same and have the "correct" dialog.

Does someone know a solution for this ? Are there any settings in VS'15 I have missed ?

*Some sources suggested unchecking the option "Enable native code debugging". This option is not enabled by default and neither is currently.*

Comment: It is the Exception Assistant.  You will not get it for any C++ project, it is only available for managed projects.  Well, it is not a C++ project.  And it is an option that you might have turned off: Tools > Options > Debugging > General.

Comment: @HansPassant That option was missing, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the following option showed the correct dialog.

Tools > Debugging > General > Enable the exception assistant

Thanks to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034).

Comment: Do consider telling us why you turned the option off.  Not exactly something you do by accident, having some insight in the "why" makes it useful Q+A.

Comment: I did not turn it off. I assume Visual Studio set it by default to off, because I choosed "C++ Environment" after it has been installed. Probably it is only checked when using the C# Environment option.